# Dedicated Ubuntu Server wont Boot

Tags: boot, server, grub2, mdadm

im new to Ubuntu.

I currently have a unmanaged dedi server from Hetzner running Ubuntu 18.04. Last night the server stopped and wont reboot, it wont respond to ping or ssh. i have 1 SSD drive and 3x1TB drives. Iused the hetzner installimage feature so not sure what raid if any, was used.

I got hetzner to activate KVM and when bios loads the cursor scrolls down the screen and just stops so i reset using ctr+alt+del and on boot screen i selected 'm' then chose linux rescue, it then ran through a list of processes, 3 of which failed.

**Failed to start LSB:openipmi driver init script**
see 'systemctl status dsm_sa_ipmi.service' for details

**Failed to start LSB: Systems Management Data Engine**
see 'systemctl status dataeng.service' for details

**Failed to start mdassemble assembles all automatically detected mdadm arrays on boot after config generation...**
see 'systemctl status mdassemble.service' for details

I closed kvm down and started hetzner rescue system.

In rescue mode i can see my disks by running

lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL, here is the output

loop0 ext2 3G
sda 111.8G
├─sda1 swap 12G (Linux/Swap)
├─sda2 ext3 512M (Linux)
└─sda3 ext4 99.3G (Linux)
sdb 931.5G
└─sdb1 xfs 931.5G
sdc 931.5G
└─sdc1 xfs 931.5G
sdd 931.5G
└─sdd1 xfs 931.5G

i tried the following to update/fix grub2

```
blkid
assumes boot partition is md1 and root is md2
mount /dev/md2 /mnt;mount /dev/md1 /mnt/boot;mount -t dev -o bind /dev        /mnt/dev;mount -t proc -o bind /proc /mnt/proc;mount -t sys -o bind /sys /mnt/sys;chroot /mnt
Or separate commands:
    mount /dev/md2 /mnt
    mount /dev/md1 /mnt/boot
    mount -t dev -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
    mount -t proc -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
    mount -t sys -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
    chroot /mnt
vi /etc/default/grub
    Fix settings e.g.
    GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5
update-grub
exit
reboot
```

I changed md1 to sda2 and changed md2 to sda3 (not sure if thats correct though)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to get to the GRUB menu? Are you able to boot in Recovery Mode? Does the server have a DVD drive that can be used to boot a Ubuntu Live DVD? Are the 1TB disks in a RAID, or set up as single disks?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Would you be so kind as to [edit] your post to include requested information and hopefully clarify what you mean by "reinstall/update grub but that didnt work" How did you attempt to do that? How did it fail? What error messages did you receive? thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I have edited my post, hope it contains relevant info, im new to this.